# xmlHttpRequest ignores g element in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, xmlhttprequest

I have an SVG file created in Inkscape. I want to use xmlHttpRequest to import the svg file and then inject the data from the `<g>` element into the HTML.

HOWEVER. The xml response for some reason omits the g element. I can see this when I evaluate the XMLResponse in the browser's debug console. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Here's what the XMLResponse puts out
[image: Here's what the XMLResponse puts out]

### SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="7e3" width="7e3" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" viewBox="0 0 7000 7000">
    <metadata>
        <rdf:RDF>
            <cc:Work rdf:about="">
                <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
                <dc:title/>
            </cc:Work>
        </rdf:RDF>
    </metadata>
    <g>
        <path d="m2757.3 5004.4-680.5-398.2-481.1 1037.3 168.3-770.3-1135.1-137 784.6-77.9-220.5-1122l316.57 722.13 998.9-556.4-588.96 524.23z" fill="#b80000"/>
        <path d="m3412.4 2163.2-160.35-542.71-560.16-80.386 466.6-320.21-96.649-557.59 448.72 344.81 500.43-264.22-189.27 533.31 405.93 394.29-565.7-15.206z" fill="#c5e100"/>
        <path d="m5368.2 4458.8-2316.6-2010.7 2271.3 3360.5-934.5-1243.8-1614.2 420 2282.8-768.5-2327 530.8 2258.9 1074.5-149.6-2017.6 490.3-524.8-2267.1 1484.9 2756.7-1066.1-2366.8 1127 1764.8 768.5 723-848.5-721.5-2303.9z" transform="matrix(.81493 0 0 .84227 1190.8 811.58)" fill="#1643bf"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

### Javascript

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var g = svg.getElementsByTagName("g")[0];

xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHTTP.onload = function() {
 if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     draw();
};
xmlHTTP.open("GET", "drawing.svg", true);
xmlHTTP.send();

function draw(){
  var svgFile, extG;
  svgFile = xmlHTTP.responseXML;// <---evaluates without the g element from the svg file
  extG = svgFile.getElementsByTagName("g");
  svg.replaceChild(extG[0],g);
};
```

Comment: Do you see the elements in `xmlHTTP.responseText`?

Comment: It’s still not clear whether `extG` is really empty.

Comment: I've had to get document.documentElement before I could I could use Dom methods on Svg

Comment: As in the image linked above, I do not see the elements inthe xmlHTTP.responseXML. And extG is empty: http://imgur.com/a/DK9Pc

Comment: Okay so actually when I enter xmlHTTP.responseText into the console, I do get the g elements in it. But NOT with xmlHTTP.responseXML.

When I change responseXML to responseText in the js file, I get the error:
svgFile.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in the comments, you cannot use regular Dom methods on SVG before getting the SVG as a DOM object.

The best way to do this is something like:

```
var svg=httpresponse.getDocumentElement();
var g=svg.getElementsByTagName('g');
```

Variable `g` then will contain a live collection of `g` elements.